# Is there a way to not use the google play store to authenticate a new update from my server?

Tags: android, google-play-services

The company I am working with develops an app that is sold with a phone; a notification pops up when the app is updated. The App is not on the Google Play Store and therefore the user needs to select that they wish to update with an ultra-net provider. I have tried to find a solution that does not point me in the direction of uploading the App to the Google play store but I have not seen any viable solution. If anyone has a suggestion I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: By selecting the check box, called Unknown Source, in the security setting of the phone, the phone will “Allow installation of apps sources other than the Play Store”. This is exactly what I needed it to do, but I would like to be able to activate and deactivate this check box in my code, when an app update is needed.

Comment: This can't be achieved if your app don't have 'system' permission. And beware that some malicious app can be accidentally installed when this option is turn on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 ways that currently in my mind:

1. App manually check to server.
2. Send messaging via [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/).
3. Using server as updater.

**First way**. We only need to check if there is an update in server. Simply by checking if current version number is lower than version number in server.
*Pros*: Server only need to provide a file with version number and apk file. No need further processing. only a simple server need.
*Cons*: No checking, client always call to server.

**Second way**. By using FCM we can 'inform' user if there is an update for the app. We only need to send message to google once, then google will transmit FCM message to every client that registered.
*Pros*: We have a huge confident that all registered user will be informed.
*Cons*: need to register all device using the app with FCM.

**Third way**. We can handle the updating process by informing each client for an update. This is almost same with using FCM.
*Cons*: minimal confident that all app user will be updated.

For First way, we can use [AppaholicsUpdateChecker](https://github.com/RaghavSood/AppaholicsUpdateChecker)

For second and third way, we can use:

1. https://github.com/EugeneWechsler/ApkUpdate
2. https://github.com/sparkleDai/ApkUpdate
3. https://github.com/NDMAC/apk-updater

For the second way, we should adjust the library above according to our need.

I've only use first way currently in my simple project.

Comment: Thank you for you response.